# I am strange that "Async" module doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-drive-api

I want to

1. Download a image file, then
2. Upload the image file to Google Drive

---

```
var async = require('async');
var fileToUpload = require('./FileToUpload.js');

var fu;

async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        /*** At first, download image file ***/
        fu = new fileToUpload.FileToUpload('http://weed.cocolog-nifty.com/wzero3es/images/scrn0000_1.jpg');
        callback(null, fu);
    },
    function (arg, callback) {
        /*** Secondary, upload the image file to Google Drive ***/
        arg.uploadToGoogleDrive();
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
]);
```

- There is **no error**, and
- the response from Google is that the **file upload succeeded**.
- In Google Drive, there is the **new file**
- but the data is broken so that **I can't open the image**.

In addition, download and upload **separately**, there is **no problem**. I can open the uploaded image in Google Drive.

Comment: What is fileToUpload ? Is this your implementation or npm package ?

Comment: I think your callback from first (download image file) function is going before your fileToUpload.FileToUpload function completes its operation

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your FileToUpload() function is contain asyncronous function because it is related to I/O. If that so, you need to execute the async waterfall's callback inside FileToUpload() function after the upload process done, that is happen inside callback of upload file function. If you're still not understand, add your complete FileToUpload() code to the question, maybe we could help

Answer (score 0):

Hand the callback to FileToUpload constructor.

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        /*** hand the async callback to the FileToUpload constructor ***/
        fu = new fileToUpload.FileToUpload('http://xxx/sample.jpg', callback);
    },
    ...
```

And call the callback inside the FileToUpload constructor.

```
// FileToUpload.js

        ...

        file.on('finish', function () {
            file.close(function () {
                callback(null, _this); /*** callback for async ***/
            });
        });

        ...
```

Thank @bagz_man for precious advice.